# next js env env local env dev env prod key/values driven through gitops

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, devops

I have a next js application where the config key/value pairs (public and private variables) are hardcoded for now. It is not so good idea to keep the secrets & urls in these files

I want to have run time environment to bring in the values

How would I do it?

All I know is we are running the Docker to bundle and run gitops in our process, the main goal is to drive secrets via gitops